# Text Change and background color change on Hover Using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 3 rows with text and on hover I want the text on the right side to change and the background color of that text as well. For some reason I can't make it work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content">string</div>
        <div class="description">A string is a series of characters.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content">number</div>
        <div class="description">A number can be written with,or without decimals.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content">boolean</div>
        <div class="description">A boolean can be either true or false.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle link:
[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/fws5yu4b/)

The result that I want to get to is this one: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US4r3.jpg)

Comment: Your code and description image are way too different

Comment: Please do not dump essential parts of the code onto an external platform only; a proper [mre] of your issue should always be contained directly in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After viewing your image description, I edited your code a little bit. Hope it will fulfill your expectation.

I just add a span tag in your description.
and added/modified some CSS.

Change details:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container {
    font-family: 'Red Hat Mono', monospace;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(178, 236, 205);
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 20px;
}

.content {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    flex:1;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.description {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'sans-serif';
    color: rgb(189, 132, 27);
    font-size: 0.95em;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.row:hover .description{
    background-color: rgb(80, 231, 150);
    color: red;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    margin-bottom: -9px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'sans-serif';
}

.row:hover .description > span{
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Red+Hat+Mono:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Tema 10</title>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content">string</div>
            <div class="description">
              <span>A string is a series of characters.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content">number</div>
            <div class="description">
              <span>A number can be written with,or without decimals.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content">boolean</div>
            <div class="description">
              <span>A boolean can be either true or false.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can make the text change ? I know it has to do with ::before pseudo but I cant figure it out where to put it.

Comment: @DenisIstrate
I don't understand what do you mean by changing text, is that you want to change style? or do you want to change the text?

If you want to know where to put it before and after you need to use it like this.
example:

`.row .description::before {
  content: "before";
}
.row .description::after {
  content: "after";
}`

See more: [::before / ::after example](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)

Answer (score 0):

Please update CSS to. You are setting font size 0 that is causing an issue

```css
.row:hover .description {
    color: rgb(0, 31, 150);
    background-color: rgb(0, 1, 0);
}
```